# Check password strength with custom validator

Tags: validation, jsf

I would like to check password strength.

Validator:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class NewAccountValidator implements Validator, Serializable
{
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/DefaultDB")
    private DataSource ds;

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) throws ValidatorException
    {
        ....
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "  Value is too long! (18 digits max)", null));
        .......
    }
}
```

How I can use this custom validator?

If it's possible I would like t make all validation logic into Java code.

I can't use SQL query to set custom validation rules configured by user.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your Validator with @FacesValidator("passwordValidator") then use it in your xhtml page as follows

```
<h:inputText value="Hello World!">
 <f:validator validatorId="passwordValidator" />
</h:inputText>
```

This link here http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.de/p/validation-in-jsf.html explains various ways to use validators in JSF